# Css long text show and hide

Tags: html, css

i have html code below like this. When the text hide i want it like the image, can you guys help me css? Thank you guys

```
<div class="text>
<p class="p-text">
The revolutionary Aquazen Flow Meter can be installed at every fixture, or any water source where you would like to get accurate water consumption. The low powered technology allows for power to run off 12V battery and the discreet size allows for easy installation under cabinets, and inside access panels. Aquazen Systems can provide elaborate weekly or monthly reports on water usage, including hot water usage, which can give major insight on how much energy each unit is drawing from the main boiler system.</p>
<span>view more</span>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/hbahar95/